# Multiple labels inside IonSelect

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to add labels inside the IonSelect. But the documentations do not show how, is there a way i can do it? I have also tried using multiple IonLabel, but it only shows one. I am using ionic v6. Note the p tags do not work, I am just trying to illustrate what i want to achieve! Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
                <IonSelect
                placeholder="Select Filter"
                multiple={true}
            >
                <p>Priority</p>
                <IonSelectOption value="high">High</IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="medium">Medium</IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="low">Low</IonSelectOption>
                <p>Status</p>
                <IonSelectOption value="open">Open</IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="closed">Closed</IonSelectOption>
                <IonSelectOption value="resolved">Resolved</IonSelectOption>

            </IonSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with the ion-select component. You would need to create a custom select using [ion-popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/popover) and design it like the ion-select.